# There are relatively prime positive integers $m,n$ such that $b-a = \frac{m}{n}$. Find $m+n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

$|x^2 - \frac{5}{2}| \le |x-8|$ if and only if $x$ is in the interval $[a,b]$. There are relatively prime positive integers $m,n$ such that $b-a = \frac{m}{n}$. Find $m+n$.
I have no clue how to approach it.Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Edit

After Googling on the problem I found that this problem is Purple Comet 2013 HS Problem 9 http://purplecomet.org/home/resource/543/2013HighSchoolProblems.pdf
Here is the solution of problem posted in AOPS
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c149h531513_purple_comet_2013_hs_problem_9

Comment: I found the same result of Khosrotash, but $b-a=\sqrt{43}$ is not a fraction $\dfrac{m}{n}$. Please check if you wrote the problem right

Comment: Yes I have written it correctly.

Comment: Then the question is meaningless, as you can see.

Comment: Its a contest problem and official answer key state that $m+n=18$

Comment: Can you tell me the contest link?

Comment: No I do not have a link. I have downloaded a pdf file.That file has this problem . All the other problems have correct answer , so I assume that this is also the case with this problem.

Comment: Can you attach an image of the PDF file with the problem?

Comment: @Raffaele Please have a look on the pdf screenshot.

Comment: OK. The problem is wrong, because I have verified using also a software and the solution of Khosrotash is correct. $b-a=\sqrt{43}$ and it is not a fraction so the question becomes meaningless

Answer (score -1):

$$|x^2 - \frac{5}{2}| \le |x-8|\\ \to \begin{cases}x^2-\frac52=x-8\\x^2-\frac52=-(x-8)\end{cases}\\x=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{43}}{2}$$
$$x\in [\frac{-1- \sqrt{43}}{2},\frac{-1+ \sqrt{43}}{2}]=[a,b]\\ \to b-a=\frac{-1+ \sqrt{43}}{2}-\frac{-1- \sqrt{43}}{2}$$